# Whether it is possible to convert Monkey test log to Monkeyrunner testing

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, monkey

In monkey test, it can output test log, which contains all random events.
I can use monkey runner to replay several events, including sending touch, sleep, switch. But, how to stimulate the track ball event in monkey runner?